# How could i get dynamic gridview in cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I am having list of gridviews with submit button created dynamically using `GridViewTemplate` class created. Whole things inserted in panel. No design in .aspx page
like in class file

```
void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (_templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:

                Label lbl = new Label();            
                Label lbl1 = new Label();
                lbl1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(lbl_DataBinding);    
                lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(lbl1_DataBinding);

                container.Controls.Add(lbl);        
                container.Controls.Add(lbl1);       
                break;
```

in aspx script at runat="server"

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
TemplateField dataid= new TemplateField();

dataid.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, "data1");

gv.Columns.Add(dataid);

gv.DataBind();

panel.Controls.Add(gv);

HtmlButton btn = new HtmlButton();

btn.ID="btn"+i.ToString()

panel.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Id:gridview1

Id:submit1

Id:gridview2

Id:submit2

How could i get the dynamic gridview on save click of button?

Comment: Question is unclear...from save button click you mean the Submit1 for grid 1 and sumbit 2 for grid 2 or there is another button on click of which you want gridviews?

Comment: I am rotating loop for list of gidview & adding dynamically in 1 Panel,some what like JAVA, if i am having ids 'gv1' & 'btn1', how i create batch update object to pass data access layer

Comment: @BreakHead: yes, **submit1** is for gridview1, i wanted to update DB on submit in disconnected mode(creating object which pass parameter to query

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic Controls I would Prefer [DynamicControlsPlaceholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) it will allows you to work with dynamically created controls, attaching events to them, finding controls etc.